# Read floats from txt (that has special characters [ ] ) and store them into 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, regex, txt

I have the following .txt file:

```
[0.03932153 0.10188484 0.23541254 0.18962094 0.43376015]    
[0.0453733  0.13984493 0.62747017 0.15459015 0.03272145]    
[0.0299296  0.1038427  0.74556143 0.03760473 0.08306153]    
[0.14998161 0.22125856 0.00924835 0.01314869 0.60636278]    
[0.09769381 0.12554495 0.0330114  0.26816809 0.47558175]
```

I want to read the containing floats and store them into a 2D array.

I tried using regex but wasn't quite sure what the right structure was.
Basicaly, do I have to use regex first to remove '[' and ']' ?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a regex to extract the numbers, and then map those to `float`:

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as f:
    result = [
        list(map(float, re.findall(r"-?\d+(\.\d+)?", line)))
        for line in f.readlines()    
    ]
```